# Encoding of files Names in PHP's ZIP Archive class

Tags: php, linux, windows, encoding, utf-8

**Setting**

- User creates a ZIP achive of a folder using Windows Explorer's ZIP feature
- The archive may contain diacritical characters like 'öäüÖÄÜß'
- User uploads the file using a POST-request, which calls a PHP script

**Problem**

> Encoding of files names is different whether the script executes on my
>   Windows test machine or the Linux production system.

**Symptoms**

I do extract information about the uploaded files in the ZIP archive using the standard [ZIP extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php):

```
$statDetails = $zip->statIndex( $index )
```

Then I emit the name of the entry:

```
echo $statDetails[ 'name' ];
```

Note, that the HTTP connection and the HTML meta describes the contents of the web page [=HTTP reply] as beeing **UTF-8 encoded**.

Output on my **Windows** test machine:

```
-RAW Test_A/2015/Dänisch/
```

On the **Linux** production machine

```
-RAW Test_A/2015/D�nisch/
```

> Note, that the file name is **no longer UTF-8** on the Linux machine.

I tried to use iconv to convert the above string on the Linux machine to Latin1 / ISO-8859-1. All characters of all file-names fit into Latin1.

Unfortunately, I failed to find a matching text encoding.

**Questions**

Due to the different results on Windows and Linux:

- **May I influence the [ZIP extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php)'s behaviour somehow?** Programmatically or by means of ini-settings?
- May I force the **[ZIP extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php) to return non-re-encoded names** of files in the ZIP?
- **Which encoding does the [ZIP extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php) use**, when I retrieve file infos using statIndex()?

Since both PHP-version are bigger than 5.2.*, they should both use zlib as [documented here](http://php.net/manual/de/zip.requirements.php).